# What is the interests of assert libraries

Tags: gruntjs, mocha.js, assert

I use Grunt to run my unit tests without assert modules, i just log what i need with grunt and use my "custom" coditions to check the variables's states and values.

I was thinking about using mocha with grunt, but i am trying to find out how it will really change something when i run my tests.
How my tests will be more valuable using mocha (for example) ?

Regarding the success of these tools, i feel like i am missing something in their utility.
If someone could explain to me how and when they are usefull, it would be really great !

Answer (score 0):

For starters, [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha) is **not** an assertion library and doesn't ship any by default.
Mocha is a testing framework which lets you describe and organize your tests, using one of several available [interfaces](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#interfaces). It also provides a report for the status of the tests after they run (and sometimes *while* they run).

You seem to be using a way of describing and running your tests already, so unless you give more details on the capabilities of your framework/runner/reporter I can't point you to mocha's (or other frameworks/runners') advantages and/or disadvantages against it. I'd like to see some of your tests and your (test-related) grunt tasks code to better assess that.

On the other hand, assertions are just checks for conditions that must be met in your tests in order to consider them "passing". An example of an assertion library for JavaScript is [chai.js](http://chaijs.com/). You mention using `"custom" conditions` (by which I don't really know what you mean), so you seem to be using some kind of asserts. The key is that if an assert happens to be false, the test from which it's evaluated must fail. If you're accomplishing that in your tests then congratulations, you're using asserts already. If you're not, then your tests are not automatic (like, for instance, if you compare your logs to their expected values manually, then you're running manual tests).

---

My comments above are all theoretically correct and you could probably live without a separate test framework, runner and assertion library. However, using a mature tool, which is also open source so it's maintained by a community of developers, will probably be more reliable than coding your own test description framework, test runner, test reporter and assertions library.

It will also point you in the right direction regarding time-tested conventions and best practices, since their features tend to help you adhere to them (or plain force them for your own good). For instance, mocha provides a simple yet tidy way of describing set-up and tear-down procedures for tests (and test suites), which if you don't implement yourself will make your tests have a lot of not-completely-relevant code, making them harder to understand and thus maintain.

Comment: @Ludo I see you got no other answers. Did this help you somehow?